# Shellshock command on pWnOS 1.0 doesnt work

Tags: cgi, vmware, virtual, shellshock-bash-bug

"So I create a quick bash script with the extension of .CGI in the /tmp directory.

Again I used the Webmin file inclusion to call the file I had created in the tmp directory and using tamper data. I used shellshock in the user-agent to add vmware to the /etc/sudoers file."

User-Agent: `() { :; }; /bin/echo "vmware ALL=(ALL) ALL">>/etc/sudoers` (in the tamper data popup). Press OK, but nothing happens. This is from a walkthrough from 2017. https://github.com/ch33z-plz/Walkthrough/wiki/pWnOS.

I need to add vmware to the sudoers.

Thanks!

I have tried doing exactly what he did. But it doesnt seem to go through. Any advice